# Ways to arrive at the existence of irrational numbers

Tags: analysis, alternative-proof, irrational-numbers

I know about a way Greeks arrived at the existence of irrational numbers by showing that sometimes two line segments can be incommensurable.

And about a simple way by which it can be shown that some numbers are irrational, for example, as is usually shown that $\sqrt2$ is irrational.

Also, it can be shown that some numbers are transcendental and because all rationals are algebraic that shows that there are some non-rational, that is, irrational numbers.

And also there is a way that shows that all rational numbers have periodic expansion in every base and since there are non-periodic expansions that also shows the existence of irrationals.

And there is countability/uncountability way.

Are there some other ways?

Comment: There are quite a few others; all sorts of ways to force a contradiction might come up. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational For example, pi turns out to be irrational because otherwise a sequence of integer-valued integrals would get arbitrarily small, a contradiction.

Comment: Personally I like the proof that $e$ is irrational; assume $e$ is rational then for some $n$ we have that $n!e$ is an integer but $n!e$ isn't an integer hence $e$ is not rational.

Comment: @kingW3: of course, showing that $n!e$ is not an integer is the nontrivial (but nor that difficult) part of the proof. I like that proof too, so I make sure I include it in my lectures anytime I teach about series. :)

Answer (score 20):

From my perspective, the key to all such proofs is *the completeness of the real numbers*.

At the most basic level, the defining property of $\mathbb{R}$ is that it is a *complete ordered field*.  Now $\mathbb{Q}$ is also an ordered field,  so you are not going to be able to prove the existence of irrationals by pure algebra or inequalities.  Somewhere you will have to use completeness.  Indeed, the existence of irrationals is equivalent to the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete but $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't.

It's interesting to look where completeness is used in the other usual proofs:

- $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational:  How do you know that $2$ has a square root at all?  There are plenty of number systems in which lots of numbers just don't have square roots (e.g. integers, modular arithmetic; even in $\mathbb{R}$ the negative numbers don't have square roots).  So what's so special about $\mathbb{R}$ to guarantee that $2$ has a square root?  Completeness, of course.  You can construct a Cauchy sequence of rationals such that if it has a limit, the square of the limit must be 2.  Or you can look at the Dedekind cut $\{x : x^2 < 2\}$.  Or you can prove the intermediate value theorem (using completeness!) and consider the continuous function $x^2$ which takes values both above and below 2.
- $\log_2 3$: Likewise, how do you know that $3$ has a log base 2?  There are lots of other number systems in which logs don't exist, e.g. there just doesn't exist any number $x$ such that $2^x = 3$.
- Continued fractions: how do you know that the continued fraction actually converges to something?
- $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable but $\mathbb{R}$ is not: you have to use completeness somewhere in proving that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.  (The Baire category theorem is a neat way to see it made explicit.)
- 0.1010010001...: why does every sequence of decimal digits actually represent a number?
- $e$: You have to first give a rigorous definition of $e$.  Whatever definition you choose, proving that there exists a number satisfying that definition will require using completeness.

Comment: Seeing how first-order logic cannot characterize countable structures, yes. You must appeal to some second-order property such as completeness.

Comment: I like this answer, but it's worth noting that other (weaker) properties of $\mathbb R$ work too - like every positive number having a square root or every odd degree polynomial having a root. One might justify these properties by appeals to completeness, but I think this is notable since, from a historical context, the notion of completeness came far later than proofs of irrationality and geometric intuition furnished the though that, for instance, $\sqrt{2}$ really ought to be a number (even if this was not formalized).

Comment: Indeed, we proved that $\mathbb{R}$ was uncountable using decimal expansion, which exists because of completeness of the real numbers.

Comment: @Milo: True. But that could only get you so far as algebraic numbers... :)

Answer (score 15):

Logorithms are an easy "in" for finding irrationals. Suppose $\log_2 3=\frac{a}{b}$. Then $3=2^{a/b}$, giving $3^b=2^a$, which is impossible unless $a=b=0$, which wouldn't be allowed by the original setup because $\log_2 3=\frac{a}{b}$ would lead to $\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: Please explain "would lead to".

Comment: @mephistolotl if $a=b=0$, then the original assumption of $\frac{a}{b}$ results in $\frac00$.

Comment: I understand the conclusion. Alex should add it to his answer.

Comment: It took me a good long while (30 seconds) to understand why you say that $3^a=2^b$ is impossible. I suspect you have in mind that the two numbers on the left and right are the same, but clearly one only has 3 as prime factor and the other only 2. But because the prime factorization of a number is unique, the two cannot be the same for $a,b$ positive integers.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth You won't need such strong results as the uniqueness of prime factorization in fact. Just observe that $3=2+1$ and $(2k+1)(2+1)=2k'+1$, which is not divisible by $2$.

Answer (score 8):

Any infinite [simple continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) is irrational because any rational number has a finite simple continued fraction.

Answer (score 3):

Your third statement is not worded correctly.  In point of fact, to show that some numbers are transcendental is not particularly easy.  The first proof for a well-known number is for $e$.  The simplest argument depends on a series of approximations (the Taylor series for $e$ that converges "too quickly" to be algebraic, but it is nowhere near as simple as the proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

There are many ways to show irrationallity, and several to show trancendentallity. For example, a number expressed as a repeating continued fraction is algebraic.

Comment: Is the argument showing that the reals are uncountable and the algebraic numbers are countable not reasonably straightforward? It certainly does not require as much machinery as proving that $e$ is irrational. On the other hand, it *does* require one to go as far as constructing the reals first, which, say, the proof that there is no rational which squares to $2$ does not.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the first number(s) that were explicitly shown to be transcendental are [Liouville's number(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number), which were tailor made for this task.  This was done in 1844; it wasn't until 1873 that Hermite prove that $\mathrm{e}$ is transcendental (at least, if [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number) is to be believed).